# Multiple domains in Next Js/React

Tags: url, next.js, dns

I have a very specific question:
Assuming my main domain is "domain.com", in my Next.js project I have the following routes:

- domain.com/john/ (John's homepage)
- domain.com/john/all_users (John's user listing page)
- domain.com/joseph/ (Joseph's homepage)
- domain.com/joseph/all_users (Joseph user listing page)
- domain.com/stephany/ (Stephany's homepage)
- domain.com/stephany/all_users (Stephany user listing page)

My question is the following: I would like to point out other domains, one for "john", one for "joseph" and another for "stephany", and that respect my path to the main domain (domain.com), for example:

- john.com/ (John's homepage, returns everything from "domain.com/john")
- john.com/all_users (John's user listing page, same as "domain.com/john/all_users")
- joseph.com/ (Joseph home page, returns everything from "domain.com/joseph")
- joseph.com/all_users (Joseph user listing page, same as "domain.com/joseph/all_users")
- stephany.com/ (Stephany's home page, returns everything from "domain.com/stephany")
- stephany.com/all_users (Stephany user listing page, same as "domain.com/stephany/all_users")

Of course, the domains "john.com", "joseph.com", "stephany.com" and "domain.com" are merely illustrative.

In short, I need to point to a different domain for each "user" route I have, respecting the respective paths.

Note: I know how to deal with the basics of DNS and domain redirection.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, using edge functions from vercel

Comment: nextjs serverless function that get deployed on edge function? I hosted it on AWS amplify how it be configured on AWS? please share example of edge function!

Comment: The next one running on AWS needs a lot of configuration for serverless to work correctly, I chose to host on Vercel as default. To create the Edge function, I just created a middleware in the root folder of my project, follow the doc link: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions and https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

Comment: Thanks! it's done with middleware, AWS Amplify services works exact like Vercel and Netlify https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplifysupport.html

Comment: This was very useful! I really didn't know about this AWS service even though I used dozens of services almost every day for years!